# MathJax config for web, mobile, and assistive

Tags: ios, uiwebview, mathjax, accessibility

Input:

```
<ins class="marked-for-jax">\[
1 + 2 + 3 + \ldots + n = \frac{n(n+1)}2.
\]</ins>
```

MathJax Config:

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],
  extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
  messageStyle: "none",
  TeX: {
    extensions: ["AMSmath.js", "AMSsymbols.js", "noErrors.js", "noUndefined.js"]
  }
});
```

MathJax output, shortened and formatted for clarity:

```
<p>
  <ins class="marked-for-jax">
    <span class="MathJax_Preview" style="color: inherit;"></span>
    <div class="MathJax_Display" style="text-align: center;">
      <span class="MathJax" id="MathJax-Element-2-Frame" tabindex="0" data-mathml="[mathML data here]" role="presentation" style="position: relative;">
        <nobr aria-hidden="true"><span class="math" id="MathJax-Span-12" role="math" style="width: 14.517em; display: inline-block;"><!--lots of nested spans here--></nobr>
        <span class="MJX_Assistive_MathML MJX_Assistive_MathML_Block" role="presentation"><!--lots of mathML here--></span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <script <!--does not impact any output. Why is it even there at all?--> type="math/tex; mode=display" id="MathJax-Element-2">1 + 2 + 3 + \ldots + n = \frac{n(n+1)}2.</script>
  </ins>
</p>
```

Appearance on UIWebView. Notice that we are seeing the output twice. The first one comes from the nested spans; the second one comes from the assistive. 
[image: seeing double]

If I strip out the assistive one with CSS, we do indeed only see the output one time. But then VoiceOver users hear nothing. Alternatively, I could strip out the nested spans with CSS. I am suspicious of that approach because, while it would likely work on iOS, it likely would not work on all browsers. Additionally, depending on exactly how I am using the output, I may want to be able to prevent MathJax from outputting portions of what it is currently doing in the first place. For example, in some cases, I will be using the Html in a way that I can be sure will appear on iOS only. In such a case, any Html that I am stripping out with css, I would prefer not to have in the first place.

How can I get the output to make sense for both sighted and assistive users?

EDIT: I found a related question here: [MathJax is duplicating my equations -- why and how can I fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29357809/mathjax-is-duplicating-my-equations-why-and-how-can-i-fix-this#)

Further edit: I can get rid of the "seeing double" problem with the following CSS, derived from here: http://mathjax.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options/assistive-mml.html. But then I have a new problem -- VoiceOver does not speak any math.

```
span.MJX_Assistive_MathML {
    position:absolute!important;
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
    padding: 1px 0 0 0!important;
    border: 0!important;
    height: 1px!important;
    width: 1px!important;
    overflow: hidden!important;
    display:block!important;
}
```

Comment: You do not show the command that loads MathJax (and the configuration file that is specified there -- I assume you are using one since you aren't loading the AssistiveMML extension yourself).  There should already be styling in place to make the assistive version not be shown.  Perhaps your page CSS is disrupting that.  Can you make a jsFiddle or codebin example that exhibits the problem?  Also, the "relate question" isn't, as that was from long before the AssitiveMML was available.  This is likely a CSS issue.

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand how to make fiddles public. Working on it.

Comment: OK, got it. Three versions of the fiddle, with varying amounts of css, linked below. All three of them have the same problem.https://jsfiddle.net/verybadcat/cjajbnj8/1/ https://jsfiddle.net/verybadcat/cjajbnj8/2/  https://jsfiddle.net/verybadcat/cjajbnj8/3/

Comment: None of these actually include MathJax itself (only its output).  That is not sufficient, in general, as this is not the same as how your program works, and that is what we need to see, not the output.  The reason that you are getting two copies in this particular case is that the CSS that you list does not include the CSS that is added by the AssistiveMML extension (which does the hiding of the MathML).  (Your first two fiddles are broken because the css files aren't even found.)  If you include the CSS inserted by AssistiveMML then it works correctly for me.

Comment: @DavideCervone, trying to follow your CSS suggestion, as best I understand it, which apparently is not very well. See my further edit above.

Answer (score 1):

PARTIAL ANSWER was to put the following CSS in. Note that this is specific to my iOS/droid offline scenario. For those of you who have different scenarios, it may not apply. Furthermore, some things come out pretty bad. I'm not exactly happy with it.

```
[aria-hidden="true"] { display: none; }
```